# Maximum user limit at the same time on linux server

Tags: linux, webserver

I have a drupal website on linux server and I want to know that is there any method to prevent user accessing after a limit number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit you  httpd.conf file and change the MaxClients.

Restart the server

Hope this helps